# Modify Django AutoField start value

Tags: django, postgresql, auto-increment, django-south

I have and existing database, which I have migrated with SQLAlchemy to a new PostgreSQL database.

I moved all primary keys with the same values as before. Now I have tables filled with data, but the associated sequences starts from 1. I have pk values stored 1 to 2000.

Now, when I try to save something with Django, I have the

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   regarding to the Primary Key.

How can I modify the sequence start values or escape this situation?
My current solution is:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
    for table_name in table_names:

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
        SELECT setval('%s_id_seq', (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM %s));
        """% (table_name, table_name))
```

It works for me, but I don't like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Ways to set / reset a sequence in PostgreSQL

(not necessarily to `max(id)`).

- There's the simple way you have in the question. You can set the sequence to start at an arbitrary number with [`setval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html):

  ```
  SELECT setval('tbl_id_seq');
  ```
- Then there's the standard SQL way with [`ALTER SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html) doing the same:

  ```
  ALTER SEQUENCE myseq RESTART WITH 1;
  ```
- If you like to restart your sequences at numbers other than the default 1:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE foo(id serial, a text);      -- creates sequence "foo_id_seq"
  INSERT INTO foo(a) VALUES('a');           -- seq. starts with --> 1

  ALTER SEQUENCE foo_id_seq START WITH 10;  -- doesn't restart sequence
  INSERT INTO foo(a) VALUES('b');           --> 2

  ALTER SEQUENCE foo_id_seq RESTART;        -- restarts sequence
  INSERT INTO foo(a) VALUES('c');           --> 10
  ```
- And there is another way, when you empty a table with [TRUNCATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-truncate.html):

  ```
  TRUNCATE foo RESTART IDENTITY;
  ```

  Implicitly executes `ALTER SEQUENCE foo_id_seq RESTART;`