# How to set primary key, then convert to autofield?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I have a model called `Document`, and I want to add a new table, `DocumentCluster` that sits above it, with a foreign key to `Document`.

```
class DocumentCluster(models.Model):
    sub_document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
    ...lots of fields here...
```

When I add this table using South, I need to fill it in by setting the primary key and the foreign key to the same value.

For example, if I currently have a `Document` object with a `pk` of 12, the new `DocumentCluster` object will have a `pk` of 12 and a foreign key to `Document` number 12.

While it may seem strange that we need the `DocumentCluster` `pk` values to match the foreign key values there is an important reason.  We use the `Document` `pk` in our URLs, but after the change the URLs will load a `DocumentCluster`, not a `Document`, so we'll need the `pk` in `DocumentCluster` to be the same as it was in `Document`.

Once that's done, I want the PK of the `DocumentCluster` to be an AutoField, incrementing from the highest value that was migrated.

Can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need to set the pk? As a natural key it should be unrelated to the content. You have the fk to determine the relationship.

Comment: We use the PK in our URLs, but after the change the URLs will load a `DocumentCluster`, not a `Document`, so we'll need the PK to be the same as it was previously.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a FK *from* `DocumentCluster.pk` *to* `Document` and at the same time make `DocumentCluster.pk` a [**`serial`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788) column. That's a contradiction. It would have to be two separate columns. I suppose you mean the other way round: ***from*** `Document` ***to*** `DocumentCluster`.

This can be done with SQL DDL commands:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE DocumentCluster (pk serial, lots text, of_fields int, ...);

INSERT INTO DocumentCluster (pk, lots, of_fields, ...)
SELECT pk, lots, of_fields, ... FROM Document
ORDER  BY pk; -- optional

ALTER TABLE DocumentCluster ADD CONSTRAINT DocumentCluster_pkey
PRIMARY KEY (pk);  -- could be integrated in CREATE TABLE

ALTER TABLE Document  -- and not the other way round!
ADD   CONSTRAINT pk_fk FOREIGN KEY (pk) REFERENCES DocumentCluster(pk);

SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('DocumentCluster', 'pk'), max(pk))
FROM   DocumentCluster;  -- update SEQUENCE to highest value

COMMIT;
```

- Your obfuscation layer (Django) may be using double-quoted names like `"Document"`, in which case you'd have to do the same ...
- [About `setval()`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html)
- [About `pg_get_serial_sequence()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)
- The PK could be declared in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, but it's cheaper to add it after rows have been inserted - assuming `pk` is `unique not null`.

More explanation and links:

- [Manually update the counter used for generation of primary key in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818345/manually-update-the-counter-used-for-generation-of-primary-key-in-hibernate/23818603#23818603)
- [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync/23390399#23390399)
- [Modify Django AutoField start value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504513/modify-django-autofield-start-value/7655273#7655273)

Comment: I think your SQL is correct but there is no reason mlissner cannot have both a serial pk and the sub_document foreign key in the DocumentCluster model.  And I'm not sure what you are referring to by 'Obfuscation layer'.  The SQL would be more clear if you added in the sub_document field/column.

Comment: @nmgeek: Like I wrote: it would have to be two separate columns - like you suggest, too. In theory the referencing column can be a `serial`, too. But it hardly makes sense to draw values from a sequence, while they must be a reference to the key in another table. I clarified a bit. I did not add the `sub_document` field because I don't think its needed after I reversed the direction of the FK.

Comment: As I said in the original question, I am really hoping to do this as much as possible with South so I can have all the benefits it brings. If there's a way I can migrate the data using South, then update the pk to be serial, that'd be my preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using south this is much simpler than I thought it would be.

Use the south *schemamigration* command as usual to build the schema migration that adds the DocumentCluster model.

Then use the *datamigration* command to build a skeleton for the next migration:

```
./manage.py datamigration yourapp populate_clusters
```

Then fill in the *forwards* method in the resulting python migration file so it looks like:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    max_id = -1
    clusters_added = 0                                                                                                         
    for document in orm.Document.objects.all():
        cluster = orm.DocumentCluster()
        cluster.id = document.id
        cluster.sub_document = document
        cluster.save()
        max_id = max(max_id, document.id)
        clusters_added +=1
    if max_id >= clusters_added:
        orm.DocumentCluster.objects.raw("SELECT "\
           "setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('yourapp_documentcluster',"\
                                         "'id'), %d)" % max_id+1)
```

(The *reverse* method in this datamigration would simply delete all the DocumentModel instances.)

If this 'populate_clusters' migration step is run right after the migration step that added the DocumentCluster table then the DocumentCluster table is empty and the serial/autokey counter starts at zero.  If you never deleted any *Documents* then the serial/autokey counter value will end up at the next unused value for *Document* pk values and you don't even have to bump it up as shown in Erwin's answer.

If, however, you have deleted *Document* instances or if somehow an *id* value was skipped then you'll need to bump up that serial/autokey counter using SQL.  Django provides a way to directly execute raw SQL.  (I don't think you can do without using raw SQL).

For safety sake you should check if cluster.id is <= the maximum document.id value seen in the loop.

Comment: This looks like a much better answer for my purposes. I'm surprised Django will let you manually set the value of a primary key, but if that's all it takes, then we're in business!

Comment: While working on something else, I found that Django actually has documentation on manually setting auto primary keys. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#explicitly-specifying-auto-primary-key-values